# Updating a dictionary privately?

Tags: python

I have a class object that receives some data. Based on a condition, I need that data to change, but *only* under that condition. Problem I'm running into is that when I call `dict.update()` , it updates the original variable too. So a subsequent request comes in, and now that original variable is "tainted" so to speak, and is using overridden information that it shouldn't have.

Assuming a dictionary like this:

```
my_attributes = {"test": True}
```

And some logic like this:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, attributes):
        if my_condition():
            attributes.update({"test": False})
```

The end result:

```
>>> my_attributes
{'test': False}
```

So, the next time `MyClass` is used, those root attributes are still overridden.

I've seemingly gotten around this problem by re-defining `attributes`:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, attributes):
        if my_condition():
            attributes = {}
            attributes.update(my_attributes)
            attributes.update({"test": False})
```

This has seemed to get around the problem, but I'm not entirely sure this is a good, or even the right, solution to the issue.

Comment: You need to make a copy of the data. See `copy.copy` or `copy.deepcopy`.

Comment: `attributes` is reference. If you want to copy dict use `priv_attributes = {**attributes}`

Comment: attributes = dict(my_attributes) creates a shallow clone and if you need deepcopy you need to write it by yourself :D
attributes['test'] = False

Comment: You are updating the object passed to your constructor, **so of course that object is updated**. Likely, you want to make a copy of that object, but given your code, I'm not sure what the point would be since you would then just discard it

Comment: not _entirely_ sure why my questions being downvoted. I figured it was a clearly detailed question about a misunderstanding of python. Thanks for the help though everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def my_condition():
        return True

    def __init__(self, attributes):
        self.attributes = {**attributes}
        if MyClass.my_condition():
            self.attributes["test"] = False


my_attributes = {"test": True}
cls_obj = MyClass(my_attributes)
print("my_attributes:", my_attributes, "class.attributes:", cls_obj.attributes)
```

Output:

```
my_attributes: {'test': True} class.attributes: {'test': False}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass a (mutable) dictionary reference to an object. Now, you have two owners of the reference: the caller of the constructor (the "external world" for the object) and the object itself. These two owners may modify the dictionary. Here is an illustration:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> def ctor(d): return [d] # just build a list with one element
>>> L = ctor(d)
>>> d[1] = 2
>>> L
[{1: 2}]
>>> L[0][3] = 4
>>> d
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

How do you prevent this? Both owners want to protect themselves from wild mutation of their variables. If I were the external world, I would like to pass an immutable reference to the dict, but Python does not provide immutable references for dicts. A copy is the way to go:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> L = ctor(dict(d)) # I don't give you *my* d
>>> d[1] = 2
>>> L
[{}]
```

If I were the object, I would do a copy of the object before using it:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> def ctor2(d): return [dict(d)] # to be sure L[0] is *mine*!
>>> L = ctor2(dict(d)) # I don't give you *my* d
```

But now you have made two copies of the object just because everyone is scared to see its variables modified by the other. And the issue is still here if the dictionary contains (mutable) references.

The solution is to spell out the responsibilities of each one:

```
class MyClass(object):
    """Usage: MyClass(attributes).do_something() where attributes is a mapping.
    The mapping won't be modified"""
    ...
```

Note that this is the common expected behavior: unless specified, the arguments of a function/contructor are not modified. We avoid side effect when possible, but that's not always the case: see `list.sort()` vs `sorted(...)`.

Hence I think your solution is good. But I prefer to avoid too much logic in the constructor:

```
class MyClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def create_prod(attributes):
        attributes = dict(attributes)
        attributes.update({"test": False})
        return MyClass(attributes)

    @staticmethod
    def create_test(attributes):
        return MyClass(attributes)

    def __init__(self, attributes):
        self._attributes = attributes # MyClass won't modify attributes
```